Boost.Process и ошибка линковщика
Пытаюсь скомпилировать приложение, использующее Boost.Process из boost версии 1.75.0, про помощи MSVS2017 и получаю ошибку:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_75.lib'

Не могу понять, откуда это берется: Boost.Process же должен быть Header Only библиотекой, откуда могут взяться зависимости к каким-то скомпилированным библиотекам?
Тот же самый код по Linux с make и g++ собирается без указания каких-то дополнительных библиотек.
Куда смотреть в поисках источника проблемы?

Очевидно, что ваше приложениее использует еще и Boost.Filesystem.

@user7860670 А как можно посмотреть, откуда у этого ноги растут? Под линуксом обычно хотя бы пишет, какой символ вызвал неизвестный референс.

А у вас ошибка о том, что библиотека не найдена, а не о том, что символа нет. Ищите, где у вас инклюдятся заголовочные файлы Boost.Filesystem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=msvc-170

Включите дефайн BOOST_PROCESS_USE_STD_FS он определяет будет ли boost.process использовать стандартную реализацию filesystem или собственную (boost.filesystem).
см. https://github.com/boostorg/process/blob/develop/include/boost/process/filesystem.hpp#L8C8-L8C32
